# Display a div when clicked over a button

Tags: jquery

here am trying to display a `<div>` with `id="importLocations"` and when I click over button "go" - its all working fine but I want to do it using jquery, but I can't make it work:

```
<script>
   function onClickButton(){
      alert("Came inside");
      document.getElementById('importLocations').style.display ='inline';
   }
</script>
<label>Functions/Tools :</label>
 <select id ="selFunction" name ="selFunction" class ="DataEntryField">
<option value ="Select">Select</option>
<optgroup label="Import From">
<option value ="1">India</option>
<option value ="2">America</option>
<option value ="3">china</option>

</optgroup>             
 </select>
<input type="button" value="Go" id="functionBtn" onClick="onClickButton()" class = "input"/>

<div id="importLocations" style="display:none;" class="header">
 <span id="locatinCaption">Import Location</span> <span class="close">
 <img id="closeLoc" width="15px" height="15px" alt="Close this section" src="/resources/images/crossMark.gif"/></span>
<br/>
<label class="DataEntryLabel"> Search by </label>
<input  type="text" id="importLocation" value="select" size="30" readonly="readonly"/>
 <input  type="text" id="searchTextArea" size="30" class="DataEntryField"/>
 <button type="button" id="importLoc" value="importLoc" class="DataEntryButton"/>search</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you make us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please show the jQuery code you've tried as well.

Comment: @Juhana I feel there's no jQuery code here... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `<head>`, add this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use it this way:

```
function onClickButton(){
    $('#importLocations').show();
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/PLvtc/1/

Or, unobtrusively:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#functionBtn').click(function(){ 
        $('#importLocations').show();
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/PLvtc/2/

Comment: @ praveen n simultaneously i want the text which i select from the dropdown to b printed over the text box wen i click on "go" button

Comment: Do you mean the textbox near `Search by`?

Comment: @shona Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/PLvtc/3/

Comment: hey i did n got det... thnx:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#functionBtn').click(function(){ 
$('#importLocations').show();
});
});
</script>
```

Place these script tags in the Head section of your page.